# How to populate select fast and only once

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have over 3200 rows in a Google Sheet. I need a dropdown with each value on a web app.

> I have this in Apps Script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('CensusWebApp2');
  var streets = getStreets();
  var businessNames = getbusinessNames();
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  htmlOutput.streets = streets;
  htmlOutput.businessNames = businessNames;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
function getbusinessNames(){
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var StreetDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("businessNames"); 
  var getLastRow = StreetDataSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];  
  
  return_array= StreetDataSheet.getRange(2,1,getLastRow-1,1).getValues();
  return return_array;  
}
```

> This is the HTML code

```
 <select type="select" name="IntestazioneTari" id="IntestazioneTari" class="form-control" >r>
        <option value="" ></option>
  <? for(var i = 0; i < businessNames.length; i++) { ?>      
  <option value="<?= businessNames[i] ?>" ><?= businessNames[i] ?></option>
  <? } ?>
  </select><be>
```

I'm creating an app similar to surveys forms, but this dropdown will be the same for every entry.

Is there a way to load this only once and not every time the form is submitted and got again for a new survey entry? (from the same operator/device)

Comment: This question requires more focus as it includes two questions. As it already got an answer about the second question, I suggest you to remove the first one, "How to improve performance?" part, and post a new question for that part. In your following question please include a [mcve] (the html part is uncomplete)

Comment: What does take more time: to run the `getStreets` and `getbusinessNames`, or making the template? (you can use `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` to time it)

Comment: @Martí If I remove `getbusinesNames` it loads fast, a lot slower with this new dropdown. And I still don't get how the global variable will persist after a submit. Is there a way to separate the page that makes the submit from the page holding the data? data never varies

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to use the value of `businessNames` retrieved from Google Spreadsheet at HTML side.
- The value of `businessNames` is not changed. So you want to load the value only one time.

In this case, how about declaring the value in the tag of `<script>` as a global? When this point is reflected to your script it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, your HTML side is modified.

```
<select type="select" name="IntestazioneTari" id="IntestazioneTari" class="form-control" >r>
<option value="" ></option>
<? for(var i = 0; i < businessNames.length; i++) { ?>      
<option value="<?= businessNames[i] ?>" ><?= businessNames[i] ?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>

<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="test()">
<script>
const value = JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(businessNames) ?>);  // Here, the value of "businessNames" is retrieved.

function test() {
  console.log(value);
}
</script>
```

- In this modification, when the HTML is loaded, the value of `businessNames` is added to the HTML by `evaluate()` method. At that time, `businessNames` is given to HTML and Javascript. By this, `const value = JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(businessNames) ?>);` has the value of `businessNames`. In order to confirm this value, when you click a sample button of `<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="test()">`, you can see the value at the console. By this, you can use the value of `businessNames` at the Javascript side after HTML is loaded.

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: I added this in HEAD section `<script>var businessNames ;</script>`and got this error the first time I submitted the form `ReferenceError: businessNames is not defined (línea 172)`

Comment: @German Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I added this in HEAD section <script>var businessNames ;</script>and got this error the first time I submitted the form ReferenceError: businessNames is not defined (línea 172)`, I'm worry that you might not correctly reflect my proposed script. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you add your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I added the full code for both HTML and .gs. I really appreciate your help Tanaike.

Comment: @German Thank you for replying and adding more information. When I tested your script, I confirmed that the value from `businessNames` can be shown in the console when I clicked "OK" button. From this, it is found that the loaded value of `businessNames` can be used by Javascript. So unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `ReferenceError: businessNames is not defined`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @German For example, in the current my modified script, the value of `businessNames` is declared as `value`. If you want to use the value as `businessNames`, how about declaring `businessNames = JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(businessNames) ?>);`? But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect, I apologize for this. And, in this case, at first, I would lie to recommend to use a simple sample script. By this, it will help to understand the modified script.

Answer (score 0):

As the values from the spreadsheet won't change, I created a really long text row with all the options and pasted them directly in the HTML.

I made the same with the other information. Load time decreased enormously.

This is the code I use to generate the values:

```
  return_array= "<option>" + businessNamesSheet.getRange(2,1,getLastRow-1,1).getValues().join("</option><option>")+"</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about performance, and there are 3 things you need to do when doing so:

1. Make measurements
2. Make measurements again
3. And make some more measurements

A change in the code could have a negative impact for a reason that you didn't expect (it's hard to keep every single little detail in mind). When making a Google Apps Script web app, you have 3 reported times:

1. The timings in your browser. How much did it really take to load the entire page
2. The running time on Google Apps Script execution log.
3. Small timing inside your application using `console.time` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)), `console.timeLog` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeLog)) and `console.timeEnd` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd)) (collectively called console timers).

Note that the first 2 may change without you changing a thing, probably because of the inner working in Google.

So let's start doing what I said: measuring. I'd measure:

1. The entire `doGet` function
2. The `getStreets()`
3. The `getbusinessNames()`
4. The `template.evaluate()`
5. How much time it takes to load the page (browser)

This will give me a rough idea on what takes most of the time. Knowing that, you can try the following ideas.

Note that I don't have your code so I can't tell how it will effect your times, so your mileage may vary. Also note that most ideas could be implemented simultaneously, this doesn't mean it's a good idea and can even slow what a single idea could have achieved.

### Idea 1: Copy the generated options into the template

If you don't need to load the options from somewhere (like I suppose you are doing), you could generate the template once, copy the generated options and paste it to the HTML. This will obviously avoid the problem of having the request the list of options and evaluating them every time, but you lose flexibility.

### Idea 2: Having the options in code instead of somewhere else

If the options won't change or you will be changing them, you could add them into your code:

```js
const BUSINESS_NAMES = `
business 1
hello world
another one
and another one
`

function getbusinessNames() {
  return BUSINESS_NAMES
    .split('\n')
    .filter(v => !!v) // remove empty string
}
```

It's similar to idea 1 but it's easier to change the values when needed, specially when using the V8 support for multi line strings.

### Idea 3: Use a Google Apps Script cache

If what's taking time is querying the options, you could use `CacheService` ([see reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)). This would allow you to only query the options every X seconds (up to 6 hours) instead of every time.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  // [...]

  const cache = CacheService.getScriptCache()
  let businessNames = cache.get('businessNames')
  if (businessNames == null) {
    businessNames = getbusinessNames()
    cache.put('businessNames', businessNames, 6*60*60)
  }
  
  // use businessNames
  // [...]
}
```

In this case I've only done it with `businessName` but it can also be use in `streets`.

having a 6 hour cache means that it could take up to 6 hours for a change in the list to propagate. If you add the options manually you could add a function to force the reloading it:

```js
function forcecacheRealod() {
  cache.put('streets', getStreets(), 6*60*60)
  cache.put('businessNames', getbusinessNames(), 6*60*60)
}
```

### Idea 4: Improve how you load the data

Is very common for new Google Apps Script users to iterate the rows one by one getting the value. It's way more efficient to get the proper range with all the rows and columns and call `getValues` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)).

### Idea 5: do a fetch instead of submitting the form

If what is happening is that it takes time to load after sending the data, it might be a good idea to use `google.script.run` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run?hl=en)) instead of making a form and submitting it, since it could prevent reloading the entire page again.

### Idea 6: SPA web app

The result of doubling down on the last idea. Same benefits and you could load the necessary data in the background while the user lands on the home page.

### Idea 7: Load the options dynamically

Use `google.script.run` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run?hl=en)) to load the options once the page has already been loaded. May actually be slower but you can give faster feedback to the user.

### Idea 8: Save the options in localStorage

Requires idea #7. Save the dynamically loaded options into `localStorage`([see reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)) so the user only needs to wait once. You may need to load them once in a while to make sure they are up-to-date.

### References

- [Console timer (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#timers)
- [CacheService (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)
- [Range.getValues() (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API) (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run?hl=en)
- [Window.localStorage (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)